# Создание сводной таблицы Excel в Java

Tags: java, excel

Необходимо создать сводную таблицу Excel из Java в формате "Классический макет сводной таблицы", то есть в виде 2003 Excel.

В Apache POI - данного функционала не нашел, SmartXLS - платный.

Есть ли какие библиотеки для создания?

Comment: Вернитесь к истокам https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/2006.01.blogtales(en-us).aspx и еще поиск по PivotTable.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet();

        //Create some data to build the pivot table on
        setCellData(sheet);

        XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet.createPivotTable(new AreaReference("A1:D4"), new CellReference("H5"));
        //Configure the pivot table
        //Use first column as row label
        pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
        //Sum up the second column
        pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 1);
        //Set the third column as filter
        pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.AVERAGE, 2);
        //Add filter on forth column
        pivotTable.addReportFilter(3);

        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ooxml-pivottable.xlsx");
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    }
```

В [Apache](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/CreatePivotTable.java) есть пример даже.

<sub>[Источник.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885116/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-pivot-table-in-excel-using-apache-poi)</sub>

Comment: Так пробовал, и даже указанный Вами пример запускал, но происходит формирование в сводной 2007, то есть со снятой галочкой "Классический макет сводной таблицы" в свойствах сводной таблицы, думаю проблема в том, что формирование происходит через библиотеку для 2007 Excel, в HSSF классе, метода "createPivotTable" нет.